# Definition of norm

Tags: functional-analysis

This is probably a simple one. Defining a normed vector space over a field K we ask the norm function to satisfy the equality: $||\alpha  x||=| \alpha |  \  ||x||$. However, if K is not a field of reals or complex numbers, it is unclear what $|\alpha|$ stands for.

Does this mean we ALWAYS have to first define a norm (an absolute value) $|\alpha|$ on K to define a norm on the vector space over K?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Having a norm in your vector space implies a notion of length; so you need to have a meaning for how the length of a vector is changed when multiplied by a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

In functional analysis, it is uncommon to consider vector spaces over fields that are not subfields of the field $\mathbb{C}$.